# Rally App SDK 2.0: Hardcoded data values for rallymultiobjectpicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Is it possible to input hardcoded values for a rallymultiobjectpicker? I have tried using the same method as a rallycombobox, but it does not seem to work. Is the rallymultiobjectpicker limited to getting values from a modelType? Is there any way to get values from a field on a artifact? Or is it strictly for objects? I suppose the alternative would be to use a rallycombobox with the multiSelect set to "true". However, there are no physical checkboxes, and the text field can become very crowded if there are many options selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hardcoded values for rallymultiobjectpicker is not currently supported, but that option will be available in a future version of the SDK.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it will be released soon (before/upon GA)? Or will it be after the SDK's official launch?

Comment: The fix is in our codebase now, and it should be in the next released version of the SDK (2.0p3).

Comment: Is there any way to produce the same effect in preview 2? I'm looking to use this control this for an attribute/field, rather than an object. Is there any way to accomplish this?